# How to create a module based permission in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have reviewed the policy based authorization and I don't see it suiting my need.

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application that controls clients (mobile and web) that has different sections called module in these form

1. User Management (CanView, CanUpdate,CanAdd, CanExport)
2. Transactions (CanView, CanUpdate,CanAdd, CanExport,CanProcessReversal)
   etc.

Each endpoint in the Web API will have all these permission required on some of the endpoints.

Example is

```
//Permission Required UserManagement(CanView)
[HttpGet("{page}/{pageSize}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(int page, int pageSize)
{
    // Do something
}

// I would want it to be dressed like this
[HasPermission(Module.UserManagement, Permission.CanView)]
[HttpGet("{page}/{pageSize}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(int page, int pageSize)
{
    // Do something
}
```

The implementation I am able to use is like this

```
[HttpPost] 
public async Task<ActionResult<Response<ManualAccountDebitModel>>> Post(ManualAccountDebitViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = new List<string>();
            errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(c => c.Errors.Select(d => d.ErrorMessage)).ToList();
            var modelResponse = Response<ManualAccountDebitModel>.ValidationError(errors);
            return Ok(modelResponse);
        }

        var user = GetUserProfile();

        if (!await _permissionAdapter.HasPermission(user.UserId, Module.TransactionReversal, Permission.CanPerformReversal))
            return StatusCode(403, new { Message = "You are not authorized to perform this operation" });

        var response = await _service.Create(model, user.UserName);

        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return BadRequest(ErrorMessages.Generic_Error);
    }
}
```

The check is on this line

```
if (!await _permissionAdapter.HasPermission(user.UserId, Module.TransactionReversal, Permission.CanPerformReversal))
```

How can I do this? The `AuthorizeAttribute` filter requires that every policy has to be registered in the `Startup.cs` file.

Another thing to note is that the permission comes in via the claims as they have been added during the login action and I want to always go to the db when the check is been done to always get the updated permission for the user. The reason for this is that a user's permission may be updated when the person is still logged in via the web client and he is trying to access an endpoint, if the claims has not been updated, it will still return error for that access until the person logs in again before the claim can be updated.

Comment: You can check this:[Permission-based Authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://www.zehntec.com/blog/permission-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)